# How to structure my unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am new to unit test and wondering how to start testing. The application I am currently working on, does not have any unit test. It a winform application and I am only interested to test the data layer of this application.

Here is an example.

```
public interface ICalculateSomething
{
     SomeOutout1 CalculateSomething1(SomeInput1 input1);
     SomeOutout2 CalculateOSomething2(SomeInput2 input2);
}

public class CalculateSomething : ICalculateSomething
{
    SomeOutout1 ICalculateSomething.CalculateSomething1(SomeInput1 input1)
    {
        SomeOutout1.Prop1 = calculateFromInput1(input1.Prop1, input1.Prop2);

        SomeOutout1.Prop3 = calculateFromInput2(input1.Prop3, input1.Prop4);

        return SomeOutout1;
    }

    SomeOutout2 ICalculateSomething.CalculateOSomething2(SomeInput2 input2)
    {
        SomeOutout2.Prop1 = calculateFromInput1(input2.Prop1, input2.Prop2);

        SomeOutout2.Prop3 = calculateFromInput2(input2.Prop3, input2.Prop4);

        return SomeOutout2;
    }
}
```

I would like to test these two methods in the CalculateSomething. Those methods implementation are long and complicated. How should I structure my test?

Comment: What exactly do you want to test?  calculateFromInput1 & 2?  If each of those are complex, you might want to expose them separately so that they can be tested individually.

Comment: I would like to test the calculateFromInput1 & 2 , however I cant expose them. I am in a situation where i am not allowed to change the current implementation. i understand it might not be possible to test without exposing them. If there is a way to test only the results/return values  of those methods, that would work. Thanks

Comment: Okay, check out the answers provided.  That should give you a pretty good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a reason for not using a straight-forward unit test implementation. I'd start with a basic test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CalculateSomething1_FooInput
{
    var input = new SomeInput1("Foo");
    var expected = new SomeOutput1(...);

    var calc = new CalculateSomething(...);
    var actual = calc.CalculateSomething1(input);

    Assert.AreEqual(expected.Prop1, actual.Prop1);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected.Prop2, actual.Prop2);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected.Prop3, actual.Prop3);
}
```

And then, as you add `CalculateSomething1_BarInput` and `CalculateSomething2_FooInput`, factor out some common code into helper methods:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CalculateSomething1_FooInput
{
    var input = new SomeInput1("Foo");
    var expected = new SomeOutput1(...);

    var actual = CreateTestCalculateSomething().CalculateSomething1(input);

    AssertSomeOutput1Equality(expected, actual);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as unit testing is concerned you would have to create the test methods for the functions that you want.

```
[TestMethod()]
public void CalculateSomething1()
{
    // First we have to define the input for the fucntion
    var input = new SomeInput1(); // Assumes your constructor creates the value for prop1 and prop2.  Change as needed.

    var classToBeTested = new CalculateSomething();
    var output = classToBeTested(input);

    // There are multiple ways to test if the outcome is correct choose the one that is correct for the method/output.
    Assert.IsNotNull(output);
}
```

The method above would be in a unit test project and associated class file.

**Some things to keep in mind when unit testing**

- Unit tests need to be independent
- Long complicated code should be re-factored down into smaller units of code and tested.
- Interfaces are an awesome way to remove dependencies.  The use of interfaces allows concepts such as mocking.  Mocking can be a little complicated at first so take your time when learning it.  There are several mocking frameworks out there that can help a lot.  i.e. RhinoMocks, Moq just to name a couple.

Answer (score 1):

Those are explicitly implemented properties, so you have to use an interface reference to test them.

```
var input1 = new SomeInput1();
// setup required data in input1.

ICalculateSomething calculator = new CalculateSomething();
var output = calculator.CalculateSomething1(input1);

// Have assert statements on the properties of output to verify the calculation.
```

Don't use var for `calculator`, because that will give you a `CalculateSomething` reference and the interface methods are hidden.